# makefile under freebsd does not compile (works on linux)

Tags: linux, compilation, compiler-errors, makefile, freebsd

I got the below makefile which works perfectly fine under linux as well as mac os. However it fails to do anything on `FreeBSD`, and I have no clue why. It gives the following output:

```
19:31:35 user@host:~/libhttp++/src> make
-
Making HTTP++ library..
make[1]: don't know how to make obj/libhttp++.a. Stop

make[1]: stopped in /usr/home/user/libhttp++/src/obj
*** Error code 2

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/home/user/libhttp++/src
```

I also tried `gmake`, which gives the following output:

```
19:31:35 user@host:~/libhttp++/src> gmake
-
Making HTTP++ library..
Building Lib ...
ar -rs obj/libhttp++.a obj/html.o  obj/http.o  obj/object.o
ar: warning: creating obj/libhttp++.a
ar: warning: can't open file: obj/html.o: No such file or directory
ar: warning: can't open file: obj/http.o: No such file or directory
ar: warning: can't open file: obj/object.o: No such file or directory
ar: fatal: Failed to open 'obj/libhttp++.a'
*** Error code 70

Stop.
make[1]: stopped in /usr/home/user/libhttp++/src
gmake: *** [all] Error 1
```

One issue might be that i'm trying to keep all intermediate object files as well as the lib itself in a separate subdirectory ("obj").

The problem is, I dont know much about makefiles, and the freebsd handbook as well as any example makefiles i could find via google did not help much. The makefile is basically copied from a working linux makefile I found somewhere, and well, it works on linux and mac os. Is there a way to convert it to a format which works on all 3 platforms? any help would be **much** appreciated.

**makefile:**

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# defines
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

LIBDIR       = ../lib
INCDIR       = ../include

OBJDIR       = obj
CXX          = g++
doLib        = ar -rs
doCompile    = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS)
doLink       = $(CXX) $(LFLAGS)
doClean      = rm -f *.o *~ *.a

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Library
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

OBJECTS = $(OBJDIR)/html.o \
          $(OBJDIR)/http.o \
          $(OBJDIR)/object.o

LIBXMLPATH=~/Development/libxml2_2
LIBCURLPATH=~/Development/libcurl

#CDEF += -D__FORIOS__
CXXFLAGS ?= -I ./ -I $(LIBXMLPATH)/include -I $(LIBCURLPATH)/include/curl $(CDEF) -c -ggdb -Wreturn-type -Wformat -pedantic -Wunused-variable -Wunused-label -Wunused-value -Wno-long-long

DISTLIB = http++

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# compile lib objects
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

lib:    all

all:
    @(echo -; echo Making HTTP++ library..; make $(OBJDIR)/lib$(DISTLIB).a)

$(OBJDIR)/lib$(DISTLIB).a: $(OBJECTS)
    @echo Building Lib ...
    $(doLib) $@ $(OBJECTS)

clean:
    @(echo Cleanup HTTP++ library)
    $(doClean)
    (cd $(OBJDIR); $(doClean))

install:
    @(echo Installing HTTP++ library in ../include ../lib)
    (mkdir -p $(LIBDIR); mkdir -p $(INCDIR))
    (cp -p *hpp *h $(INCDIR)/ ; cp -p $(OBJDIR)/lib$(DISTLIB).a $(LIBDIR)/)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Compiler Call
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cc
    @echo Compile "$(*F)" ...
    $(doCompile) $(*F).cc -o $@

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# dependencies
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

CHECK = def.h

$(OBJDIR)/html.o       : html.cc     $(CHECK) html.hpp
$(OBJDIR)/http.o       : http.cc     $(CHECK) http.hpp
$(OBJDIR)/object.o     : object.cc   $(CHECK) object.hp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday I found the problem:

```
 all:
    @(echo -; echo Making HTTP++ library..; make $(OBJDIR)/lib$(DISTLIB).a)
```

This line is bad when the makefile is used with `gmake`, because it calls ***make*** instead of ***gmake***. So the fix is:

```
all:
    @(echo -; echo Making HTTP++ library..; gmake $(OBJDIR)/lib$(DISTLIB).a)
```

Now it works perfectly without any adjustments when using `gmake`.

Answer (score 1):

GNU `make` has a number of extensions beyond the `make` on BSDs (which is sometimes available on non-BSD boxes as `bsdmake`).  You can look at the [FreeBSD man page for `make`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=make) to see the differences, but the most salient one is that the syntax

```
%.target: %.source
```

is only available on GNU `make` (there's a similar syntax, though less flexible, in BSD make).

I'd have thought that `gmake` would work, though.  Hmm...

Looking at the makefile, I can't see anything that creates `$(OBJDIR)`, so it *might* be that that's the problem – it's the first thing I'd try to fix, at any rate.  If so, then just `mkdir obj` beforehand might work.

Comment: Do you mean i should manually create the directory, or create a dependency/rule which creates it? because this directory already exists (also on linux i have to create this manually if it doesnt exist already).    
so how can i replace the `%.target: %.source` syntax with something which works on all systems?

Comment: I meant manually created it (supposing you want to avoid editing this makefile). If the `obj/` directory exists, then... not sure. The `$(OBJDIR)/%.o` rule looks like it should echo the file being compiled, and that's not showing in your quoted `gmake`, which puzzles me.  The command `gmake -d` will show fairly copious debugging output, indicating which files `gmake` thinks are and aren't up-to-date. Given that makefile and the bsdmake requirement, I'd be inclined to strip out the `$(OBJDIR)` stuff and (carefully) replace `%.o: %.cc` with `.cc.o:` which is the bsdmake (and gmake) alternative.